# credit update within a loop JS

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working on a simple terminal JavaScript file, which is a menu that allows the user to add a credit of their choice, remove credit and view how much credit they have available. This is in a loop in order to show the menu again after the user has chosen an option.

The problem is, if I add a set amount of credit (say £50) and then go back and add another £50, which should then make it a total of £100. It still shows the first input. The same works with removing credit and then viewing how much is left. After removing it, once I select the option to view the total credit, it's only shows the original amount (before anything was removed).

I assume this must be due to it being within a loop. But as far as I am aware, this is the only way i can do it in order to allow the menu to continue to show after an option as been selected.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You're not aggregating anything, so you only ever have the latest value available.

Change case 2 & 3 to:

```
credit += readlineSync.questionInt(...);

credit -= readlineSync.questionInt(...);
```

respectively...

Comment: Thank you very much. I wouldn't have realised the solution was something as simple as that. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks again!